# How Can I Determine If The Hash Has A Key Containing "O" And Then Return The Value of the Key Containing "O"?

Tags: ruby

I am reporting from an excel spreadsheet and I need to run tests on values in column "O"

to do this, I first have extended the `Hash` class to include a method that checks that a key exists with "O" but now I need to test the value of that key.

```
require 'creek'

class Hash
  def has_rkey?(search)
    search = Regexp.new(search.to_s) unless search.is_a?(Regexp)
    !!keys.detect{ |key| key =~ search }
  end
end

creek = Creek::Book.new "timesheet.xlsm"
sheet = creek.sheets[0]

data = {}
sheet.rows.each do |row|
  x = {}
  row.each do |key, val|
    cell = {key => val}
    x.merge!(cell)
  end
  if x.has_rkey?('O')
    #Some way of returning the value of the key containing "O"
  end
  data.merge!(x)
end
```

lets say `x` was a hash containing `{"N1" => 14, "O1" => 15}`
I want to return the value of the key containing the letter "O", which is `15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
hash = {"N1" => 14, "O1" => 15, "O2" => 16}
values = hash.select { |k,v| k.include? 'O' }.values #=> [15, 16]
```

This code uses [`Hash#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) to specify the condition, [`String#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-include-3F) to check each key and [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) to return the values in an array.

Comment: got it to work when I converted the array to a string and then an integer `x.select { |k,v| k.include? 'O' }.values.join(",").to_i`

Comment: So do you want to find the first value whose key is `"O"`? In which case is this better: `value = hash.find {|k,v| k[0] == 'O' }.first`?

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out, something like this below will make sure 'O' is the first character like you specify. `include?` will check the entire string, but that's probably ok for what you're doing.

```
values = hash.select { |k,v| k[0] == 'O' }.values
```